# MongoDB $geoWithin query very slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, geospatial

I have a huge collection of documents (~1 milion), each doc is quite big (avgObjSize: 13268). Each document has a geo point:

```
Accomodation:
    {
       "location" : {
            [...]
            "geoLocation" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    -42.61343486, 
                    71.70936503
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the following index:

```
{
    "location.geoLocation" : "2dsphere"
}
```

I do this simple query (it should keep a 85km radius):

```
db.getCollection('Accomodation').find({
            "location.geoLocation" : {
                "$geoWithin" : {
                    "$centerSphere" : [ 
                        [ 
                            2.34682537615297, 
                            48.8536252472747
                        ], 
                        0.0131543876703093
                    ]
                }
            }})).limit(100)
```

the query execution takes from 1 to 6 seconds, and I think it's slow.
Even if the server is not powerfull it should take so much less time to get 100 docs, it seems it uses the index, so the docs in the area should not even be fetched for the scan. 
What am I missing?

This is the query stats

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "Stage-BluePillow.Accomodation",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "location.geoLocation" : {
                "$geoWithin" : {
                    "$centerSphere" : [ 
                        [ 
                            2.34682537615297, 
                            48.8536252472747
                        ], 
                        0.0131543876703093
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "location.geoLocation" : {
                        "$geoWithin" : {
                            "$centerSphere" : [ 
                                [ 
                                    2.34682537615297, 
                                    48.8536252472747
                                ], 
                                0.0131543876703093
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "location.geoLocation" : "2dsphere"
                    },
                    "indexName" : "location.geoLocation_2dsphere",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "location.geoLocation" : [ 
                            "[5116089176692883456, 5116089176692883456]", 
                            "[5170132372221329408, 5170132372221329408]", 

                            [...]

                            "[5183361696126730241, 5183502433615085567]", 
                            "[5183643171103440896, 5183643171103440896]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },

    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 100,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1399,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 151,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 142,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "nReturned" : 100,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1180,
            "works" : 152,
            "advanced" : 100,
            "needTime" : 51,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 35,
            "restoreState" : 35,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "location.geoLocation" : {
                        "$geoWithin" : {
                            "$centerSphere" : [ 
                                [ 
                                    2.34682537615297, 
                                    48.8536252472747
                                ], 
                                0.0131543876703093
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 100,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1180,
                "works" : 151,
                "advanced" : 100,
                "needTime" : 51,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 35,
                "restoreState" : 35,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 142,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 142,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 40,
                    "works" : 151,
                    "advanced" : 142,
                    "needTime" : 9,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 35,
                    "restoreState" : 35,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "location.geoLocation" : "2dsphere"
                    },
                    "indexName" : "location.geoLocation_2dsphere",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "location.geoLocation" : [ 
                            "[5116089176692883456, 5116089176692883456]", 
                            "[5170132372221329408, 5170132372221329408]", 

                            [...]

                            "[5183361696126730241, 5183502433615085567]", 
                            "[5183643171103440896, 5183643171103440896]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 151,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "metasearch",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.10",
        "gitVersion" : "79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: 2 months are passed, I still have this problem, and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I think this is the expected behavior, so the documents involved in the geo query has to be fetched. I'll probably create a dedicated collection with just the point and the doc id, so the fetched docs will be lighter. Then I'll probably use another index on more large area queries.

Comment: Did you find a solution now ?

Comment: As stated in the previous comment: I think $geoWithin isn't a linear operation, so can't be used on "infinete" collections.
When I search for the accomodation, I always have a search area, something like a city or a state, let's name it "item" and it has an id. So i precalculate what are the accomodation in the item's area and added the item id to and array in the accomodations. Adding an index to the array a query on it is much performant. When I don't have the item i search form the smaller item contained in the $centerSphere